# Error calculating the number of days since the start of the year

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to calculate the number of days since a specific date, but an error surfaces at the 87th day, and lasts till the 303th day, before it returns to normal. The error is always bellow the number with a decimal number of **.958333333333**.

```
function findDays($day, $month) {return   ( (mktime(0, 0, 1, $month, $day)-strtotime("2022-01-01 00:00:01"))/86400)+1;}


$months=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]; 
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){ 
    echo "<br>month-".($i+1).": ";
    for($j=0;$j<$months[$i];$j++){
        $days= findDays($j+1, $i+1);
        echo $days." | ";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Because of the hour that's lost when we change to daylight saving time in the spring, until we change back to standard time in the fall.

Comment: Or just use [`DateTime::format('w')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: @Sammitch You mean `'z'`? *"The day of the year (starting from 0)"*

Comment: @Sammitch that wouldn't cover if you want the day number across multiple years. Of course I can add up previous years, but i rather find a way to calculate it, it's more clean.

Comment: @habibhassani To be fair to Sammitch, that was not part of your problem statement "I'm trying to calculate the number of days since the start of the year."

Comment: @rickdenhaan that's true, I corrected it. I just used it as a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to know for a particular date how many days have passed since the start of the year, you can use a date format:

```
function findDays($day, $month) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', $month . '-' . $day)
               ->format('z');
}
```

For today, April 1st 2022, that returns 90 (if you don't provide a year in the DateTime format, the current year is used).

If you want to get the number of days since a specific date, you can use a DateInterval:

```
function findDays($day, $month) {
    $baseDate = new DateTime("2020-01-01");

    return DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', $month . '-' . $day)
               ->diff($baseDate)
               ->days;
}
```

For today, that returns that 821 days have passed since January 1st 2020.